# Client-side browser socket communications for web app - Best method?

Tags: javascript, browser, client-side, payment-processing

Sorry for the cryptic title, struggling to summarise my problem in a single line...

I wish to deploy an online, hosted website to serve a series of remote terminals which will be equipped with Chip & Pin payment card readers (aka pinpads). The pinpads are driven by some software on the PC within the terminal which is written by a 3rd party. The integration methods supported by this software are either text file based or socket based with a "request" and "response" workflow.

I have successfully carried out similar integrations in the past using client side VB Script to instantiate client side COM objects which communicate via socket connection with the local 3rd party software but this approach ties me to Windows and I would prefer to keep my options open.

My web server will be Ruby On Rails based and I intend to use HTML5 and CSS3 to provide a rich experience on the payment terminals and wondered if I can use web sockets for client side communications? From what I understand, this is not what they are designed for and so I think the answer is no.

So, what are my options? Can i use client side JavaScript to carry out socket communications or is this prevented by browser security measures? From the browser's perspective it would be communicating with a specific numbered port on "localhost"

If socket comms is not possible, can I use JavaScript to create client side text files to integrate that way?

Or am I stuck with VB script and local COM objects?

Any suggestions would be most welcome and please let me know if you need clarification on any aspect of my question.

Kind regards,
Craig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can write a text file with JavaScript.  And you can't put arbitrary bytes on a socket either.  I don't completely understand you scenario.  It sounds like you have Ruby sunning on a server and JavaScript and this third party pinpad thing running on a client.  And you need the two client entities to be able to talk to each other. Could you have the browser communicate with your Ruby server (using one of many web technologies) and then have your Ruby server relay the data back to the pinpad socket.  Or is the pinpad only a local socket?

Comment: Hi, yes I have Ruby On Rails running on a hosted server delivering the bulk of the website functionality with the pinpad running on a client machine (point of sale terminal) with 3rd party software running on the client listening for incoming commands. The client is running a browser (currently IE8) and currently uses VBScript to instantiate a custom ActiveX COM object to control the pinpad via the local socket connection. I'm looking for a better solution. I hope this clarifies. Thanks!

Comment: If the pinpad thing can only listen to localhost and read local files, then you have to do something like what you are doing.  ActiveX, Java, Flash, or Silverlight.  It seems that ActiveX is the worst choice since it only works in IE and is essentially deprecated.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I only used ActiveX because I was familiar with it already. I am a Java programmer so I think I'll look into that as an option. The browser plugin option suggested by Travis Webb above is also a possibility but Java is my preference. Thanks again.

Comment: True, but then you are not cross-browser.

Answer (score 1):

The only type of socket-based connection you are allowed to open on a standard web page that runs javascript is an HTTP socket. You'll have a lot more freedom to use sockets if you develop a browser plugin, which is written in javascript. Firefox, I know, supports sockets in extensions.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsISocketProvider

Comment: Hi, thanks for this suggestion - I may well look into this if I can't find a better method. I was hoping to avoid any proprietary solutions if possible to keep platform and browser options open but that may not be possible. Thanks again.

Comment: I'll clarify that for you: by design, it **is not** possible. Browsers are specifically and purposefully designed to not allow this type of socket communication.